# Duplicating database fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL. I have table with 3 fields: id, price, count. I need to write small billing system and I have faced with some problem. Example :

1. User need the new computer. User writes price and count to the DB (e.g. 999, 1).
2. Admin has ability to confirm this price or edit. If admin confirm this price and count i need to save user price and count and admin. Have I need to create duplicate fields(e.g confirmed_price, confirmed_count) and if admin has changed this price have I need to create changed_price and changed_count fields. In this variant table will have many 0 values and would anybody can recommend me another way of solving this problen

Comment: The answer to your `2.` depends on what you intend to do with this information: what forms you need to populate, what you need to have preserved for auditing/reporting, etc.

Comment: Regardless of the schema you use, I would write the confirmed price and count on confirmation regardless of whether they have changed. If you need to inquire whether one of those values HAS been changed, you can simply compare the values for equality.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be, just create one additional column STATUS.

Once user enters, it can be 1 status (meaning just entered)
Approved - 2 
Changed - 3

While 1 and 2 can be in the same row the changed can be a separate row, while retrieving you can retrieve those records with max(status) so that you get only one record per item, even though they may have multiple ids in the database.

The same logic of status can be used in other ways to achieve the same end as well.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I need to save all values(unconfirmed, confirmed, changed). I need to display it in format: stated_price, stated_count, changed_price, changed_count ...

Comment: So all that you need to do is store each value in a row and adopt the same approach of taking the max status if you want the most updated value

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to add an extra column, but it depends on your situation.

If you do not need to store what the original price/count were, then adding a column is easy and would work like so:

```
|   ID   |   Price   |   Num   |   Verified   |
+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+
|   1    |    110    |    1    |       1      |
|   2    |    999    |    2    |       0      |
```

When verifying, you can `UPDATE` the row and when saving you change `Verified` to 1.  Then, anything that has column `Verified = 0` needs reviewing and `Verified = 1` is verified.

So, say ID 2 should have a Num of 3.  You would have the Admin edit:

```
UPDATE myTable SET Num=3 WHERE ID=2
```

Then when they click "Save"

```
UPDATE myTable SET Verified=1 WHERE ID=2
```

You can also do both at once

```
UPDATE myTable SET Num=3, Verified=1 WHERE ID=2
```

If you want to save the old values, you can easily make an archive table that can include a timestamp.  Then just insert your values into that table before running the updates.

**NOTE:**  `Count` is a bad column name as it is a keyword in SQL

Comment: but if I need to store data is the good variant to create other two fields?

Comment: @incredible_titan That would work, but it is just as easy to have an archive table that you insert the data into (along with timestamp) on every UPDATE to the live table.